# Get ASP.Net HttpContext.Current.Session start date

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Is it possible to get `HttpContext.Current.Session` start date or the only solution is to store the start date myself in the session object ?

Comment: No, looks like this information is not stored by the framework. Handle session_start and store it, just like you said

Comment: You'll have to store the date yourself in the Session object.

Comment: Andrei : please answer so I could give you my vote

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, you have to set current date / start date / whatever date when session starts. Something like:

```
void Session_Start(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  Session["Date"] = DateTime.Now.ToString();
}
```